# Resizing images within flexbox render incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

### Background

I am trying to make a div where an image is on one end with a text portion on the other (taking up the rest of the available space). The image is sized relative to the window width and the text is center-aligned within the space available.

Also, the image has icons that are absolutely positioned on it, relative to it's size.

[You can test it for yourself here](https://lnfwebsite.github.io/Streamly/#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)

HTML:

```
<div id="previousVideo" onclick="backVideo();" title="Back">
  <div class="videoNameContainer">
    <p class="videoName"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="videoImageContainer">
    <div class="videoImageWrapper">
      <img class="videoImage" src="" />
      <span class="fa fa-backward"></span>
      <p class="videoTime"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#previousVideo,
#nextVideo {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.videoNameContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.videoImageContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
  align-items: center;
}
.videoImageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.videoName {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}
.videoTime {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 3px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#previousVideo .videoNameContainer {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#previousVideo .videoImageContainer {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.fa-backward, .fa-forward {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

### Question

Upon resizing the window of Firefox, the image resizes and everything follows the CSS.

[image: Firefox]

Yet, doing the same on Chrome, the image does not resize at all:

[image: Chrome]

Why is this happening? Thanks ahead!

**UPDATE:**

On adding `width:100%` to the image, Chrome does not maintain the aspect ratio of the image:

[image: update1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you container is resizing, but the img is overflowing.

You need to add width:100% to your img, so it resizes to whatever width the container has.

```
.videoImage{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

It seems in the absense of a width declaration for the image itself, Firefox is resizing the img to the container, while Chrome is just keeping the image actual width.

Comment: It seems that when doing this, Chrome is not maintaining the aspect ratio of the image. See my update above.

Comment: if you set the height of that element to 100% as well, it starts working. not sure why. Looks like some really weird choices of dimensions on your CSS rules...

Comment: great tunes btw @HelpingHand

Comment: Thanks man! That seems to have done the trick... If you have any advise on the css dimensions, please let me know... I taught myself css, and it's more than likely that I don't understand how something works.

Comment: @HelpingHand the weird part is that you're making those parts with display:flex, but then have no "flex:",  neither flex-basis, flex-shrink / grow, nowhere. Instead you have width declarations that doesn't really make sense, like having a #nextVideo and #previousVideo flex-containers with 2 childs, .videoImageContainer with a width of 40% and .videoNameContainer with a width of 70%... which is more than 100%. Your flex items should use a flex-basis instead, an let the shrink and grow.